# Graphing x/y against y

Tags: graphing-functions

This is a question about graphing the relationship between two variables. It is about the ideal gas equation $$pV=nRT$$ to plot ${p}\over{T}$ against $T$, where ${nR}\over{V}$ is constant. How would this graph look like?

And in general, how do you plot ${x}\over{y}$ against $y$?

Comment: if you're asking how to plot $x/y=y$ then just multiply both sides by $y$ and you have yourself a parabola.

Comment: So $y^2$ = x? But that means that $y = \sqrt{x}$?

Comment: Actually, this is a question related to the ideal gas equation ($pV = nRT$). I need to plot ${p}\over{T}$ against $T$, where ${nR}\over{V}$ is constant. How would this graph look like?

Comment: well first off if $y^2=x$ then $y=\pm\sqrt{x}$, not just $\sqrt{x}$ which is indeed a parabola, just flipped on a different axis. As for your equation, I'm not sure what you mean. Is $p$ held constant?

Comment: @Jeremy p is not held constant, only n, R and V are held constant.

Comment: Before I post my answer, Are you absolutely sure that that $\frac{1}{V}$ is constant?

Comment: @Nick Yup, V is constant therefore 1/V is constant.

Comment: Dear @Jeremy, to plot $f(x)$ against $g(x)$ means that we must find all points $\Big(g(x),f(x)\Big)\in\Bbb R^2$. If you're unfamiliar with this concept: [Check out Indicator Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_volume_diagram)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do that, but plotting $p/T$ vs $T$, you put $T$ on the horizontal axis and $p/T$ on the vertical axis and plot.  You get a hyperbola, just like $y=1/x$  In your ideal gas case, if $\frac {nR}V$ is constant, so $p/T$ is, too.

Comment: Why would it be a hyperbola?

Comment: Because when you say "plot against T", you are putting T on the horizontal axis.  The value of the function is p/T, which goes on the vertical axis.  There is no magic to the names of the axes-we just typically use $x$ horizontal and $y$ vertical.  Look at [this Alpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot+1%2Fx)

Comment: Yes, but isn't p/T varying as T is?

Comment: Of course.  That is why you are plotting a graph.  You plug values of $T$ in to get points $(T,p/T)$ and plot them.

Comment: In the given isochoric setting, $P \propto T$. Hence, $P$ is not constant but $\frac{P}{T}$ is. Infact, $P$ can be considered a function of $T$ as $P(T)$. My point is, the function $f(T) = \frac{P(T)}{T}$ won't get you a hyperbola but instead it will be a constant function similar to say $f(x) = \pi$.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal gas law tells us that p/T is equal to nR/V, always, for an ideal gas.  When using this law, it may helpful to keep in mind that all of the quantities are positive.

When nR/V is constant, so is p/T, because they are always equal.  The plot of p/T vs T will be a horizontal straight line.  On the usual temperature scales, the temperatures are only positive, so the horizontal straight line should not cross the vertical axis of the plot.

In general, we might have a function y = f(x).  If we wanted to plot x/y vs y, we would need to know the function f(x).